# $lookup within the same collection is nesting docs instead of returning all docs

Tags: mongodb

Dealing with `$lookup` was fun until I thought of makeing a join withing the same collection.

Say I have the next collection:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5a1a62026462db0032897179'),
'department': ObjectId('5a1982646462db032d58c3f9'),
'name': 'Standards and Quality Department',
'type': 'sub'}, {
'_id': ObjectId('5a1982646462db032d58c3f9'),
'department': false,
'desc': 'Operations Department',
'type': 'main'}
```

As clearly it says, there's backlinking within the same collection using the `department` key which could be `false` to indicate highest level department.

I'm using the next query (Python) to populate the results:

```
query = [{'$lookup': {'as': '__department',
              'foreignField': '_id',
              'from': 'departments',
              'localField': 'department'}},
 {'$unwind': '$__department'},
 {'$group': {'__department': {'$first': '$__department'},
             '_id': '$_id',
             'department': {'$first': '$department'},
             'name': {'$first': '$name'},
             'type': {'$first': '$type'}}}]
for doc in conn.db.departments.aggregate(query): pprint(doc)
```

What I'm expecting to get:

```
{'__department': None,
 '_id': ObjectId('5a1982646462db032d58c3f9'),
 'department': false,
 'name': 'Operations Department',
 'type': 'main'},
{'__department': {'_id': ObjectId('5a1982646462db032d58c3f9'),
                  'department': 'false',
                  'name': 'Operations Department',
                  'type': 'main'},
 '_id': ObjectId('5a1a62026462db0032897179'),
 'department': ObjectId('5a1982646462db032d58c3f9'),
 'name': 'Standards and Quality Department',
 'type': 'sub'}
```

What I'm actually getting is:

```
{'__department': {'_id': ObjectId('5a1982646462db032d58c3f9'),
                  'department': 'false',
                  'name': 'Operations Department',
                  'type': 'main'},
 '_id': ObjectId('5a1a62026462db0032897179'),
 'department': ObjectId('5a1982646462db032d58c3f9'),
 'name': 'Standards and Quality Department',
 'type': 'sub'}
```

I'm not sure why `$unwind` is grouping both the docs together although before applying `$unwind` I do get both of them separatly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you create an empty array `__department` in the document that didn't find a match in the `$lookup`. This is how your orphan document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1982646462db032d58c3f9"),
    "department" : false,
    "desc" : "Operations Department",
    "type" : "main",
    "__department" : []
}
```

When you are unwinding there is nothing to `$unwind` in this document, so it gets lost in the process. If you want to keep it you have to "normalize" your array. So you'd have to add this after your `$lookup` and before your `$unwind`:

```
{
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            department: 1,
            name: 1,
            type: 1,
            __department: {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$__department", []]
                    },
                    [{
                        _id: 0,
                        department: "None", 
                        desc: "None",
                        type: "None"
                    }], '$__department'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

So all together it should look like that:

```
[{
        '$lookup': {
            'as': '__department',
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'from': 'depart',
            'localField': 'department'
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            _id: 1,
            department: 1,
            name: 1,
            type: 1,
            __department: {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$__department", []]
                    },
                    [{
                        _id: 0,
                        department: "None", 
                        desc: "None",
                        type: "None"
                    }], '$__department'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {'$unwind': "$__department"},
    {'$group': {'__department': {'$first': '$__department'},
             '_id': '$_id',
             'department': {'$first': '$department'},
             'name': {'$first': '$name'},
             'type': {'$first': '$type'}}}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. This is exactly what I needed!